# Is there a USB-to-Bluetooth converter?

Tags: usb, bluetooth

I have a USB product that I'd like to use wirelessly on my Mac Mini media center. Is there a product that connects via Bluetooth to the computer and acts as a USB hub?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid the bandwidth of Bluetooth is not sufficient for USB devices, even for USB 1.1 devices.

From [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_device_bandwidths):

```
USB Low Speed (USB 1.0)  1.536 Mbit/s 192 kB/s
USB Full Speed (USB 1.1)   12 Mbit/s  1.5 MB/s

Bluetooth 1.1           1,000 kbit/s   125 kB/s
Bluetooth 2.0+EDR       3,000 kbit/s   375 kB/s
```

There are wireless USB hubs (like [this one](http://www.iogear.com/product/GUWH104KIT/)) but they do not rely on Bluetooth for communication. I haven't used one (they're still pretty expensive) so I'd suggest you search for "wireless USB hub" on your favorite search engine for models and reviews.